# I am trying to run simple tensorflow program and trying to find loss by applying adamoptimizer. But everytime I am getting loss: 0.062401455

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

## data file link: [data.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q5Ue1jC8bSGXpVXKtrVBc_pRvyhsq1SR/view?usp=sharing)

```
enter code here

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def read_dataset():
    df=pd.read_csv("D:\\data.csv")
    X=df[df.columns[0]].values
    Y=df[df.columns[1]].values
    return X, Y
X,Y=read_dataset()

w=tf.Variable([1.0],tf.float32)
b=tf.Variable([1.0],tf.float32)
x=tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
y=tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
prediction = x*w+b
cost = tf.sigmoid(prediction)
squred_error=0.5*tf.square(y-cost)
loss=tf.reduce_sum(squred_error)
optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01)
train=optimizer.minimize(loss)
init=tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess=tf.Session()
#loss=tf.Print(loss,[loss],"Loss: ")
sess.run(init)
for i in range(100):
    result=sess.run(loss,feed_dict={x:X,y:Y})
#r2=sess.run(train,feed_dict={x:[1,2,3,4],y:[0,3,3,5]})
print('loss: ', result)
```

After running code I am getting same loss in every iteration.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q5Ue1jC8bSGXpVXKtrVBc_pRvyhsq1SR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You never do any training, what do you expect to happen? If you want the model to learn you will need to run the `train` op (many times).

Comment: yes got it.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As xdurch said in comments: you need to run the minimization operation.

```
_, loss_value = sess.run([train, loss], feed_dict={x:X, y:Y})
```